# echarts polar bar - How to make it full?

Tags: echarts

I want to make bars fit fully with circle, but there is small space between angle axis's line and outermost bar.
How can I remove this space?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `barWidth` to 100

```js
series: {
  type: 'bar',
  coordinateSystem: 'polar',
  barWidth: 100
}
```